# Why do I need to add NULL termination in my const char arrays?

Tags: arrays, c, char

edit: meant 'null termination' wherever 'padding' is used.

I am using the following function to compare a string (in this case the argv[1]) to an array of accepted arguments.

```
const char *ARGS_HELP[] = {"-h", "--help", "-help", "help", NULL};
const char *ARGS_BUILD[] = {"-b", "--build", NULL};

int strcmp_array(char *a, const char *b[])
{
        //printf("a = \"%s\"  b[0] = \"%s\" b[1] = \"%s\" b[2] = \"%s\" b[3] = \"%s\" b[4] = \"%s\" b[5] = \"%s\" b[6] = \"%s\ \n",a,b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5],b[6]);
        int len = 0;
        while (b[len] != NULL)
        {
                len++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
                //printf("Comparing \"%s\" to \"%s\"\n",a,b[i]);
                if (strcmp(a, b[i]) == 0)
                {
                        return 0;
                }
        }
        return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1 || strcmp_array(argv[1], ARGS_HELP) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s", HELP_PAGE);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I noticed that when I ran my program with "--build" as argv[1], it would still trigger the help page. I wondered why since ARGS_HELP and ARGS_BUILD are two separate const char arrays.
I noticed strcmp_array was looping through all the possible combinations. This is because I had not inserted NULL at the ends of each array to signify its end. Who can explain why this happens, why doesn't the compiler automatically insert a NULL character at the end of the const char arrays?

With padding

```
const char *ARGS_HELP[] = {"-h", "--help", "-help", "help", NULL};
const char *ARGS_BUILD[] = {"-b", "--build", NULL};

a = "--build"  b[0] = "-h" b[1] = "--help" b[2] = "-help" b[3] = "help" b[4] = "(null)" b[5] = "(null)" b[6] = "-b"
```

Without null padding

```
const char *ARGS_HELP[] = {"-h", "--help", "-help", "help"};
const char *ARGS_BUILD[] = {"-b", "--build"};

a = "--build"  b[0] = "-h" b[1] = "--help" b[2] = "-help" b[3] = "help" b[4] = "-b" b[5] = "--build"
```

I should always pad my char arrays with NULL from now on?

I am not a computer scientist. I am relatively new to C.

Comment: That's not padding at all, that's a terminator/sentinel value. That's what tells you when you're out of elements in the array of pointers, without needing to know the length. On "why doesn't the compiler automatically insert a NULL character at the end of the const char arrays", why should it? The array will contain what you specify that it does.

Comment: The function does not know the length of the array, so a **sentinel** value is used: `NULL`. You loop stops when this is reached: `while (b[len] != NULL)`. It has the same role as the NUL terminator used at the end of a C string, which again carries no length information. If course, you can choose to pass the array length instead. Note that `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` uses *both* methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't padding, it's adding a trailing `NULL` so that iteration of these structures is super simple. You just move along until you hit a `NULL`, then stop. It's *especially* common with lists of `char*` strings, like this, but you will also see it on lists of `struct` pointers and in other situations.

This is not unlike now C strings are `NUL` (character) terminated. In other languages you need not only the character data, but a length field as well, which adds overhead and complexity.

The alternative is you'd have to know how many there are, then pass that information in as well, which is a hassle, especially if you get that number wrong.

It's not that you have to, it's that it makes it convenient *if* the code you're using expects things to work that way. Notice how `argc` and `argv` are provided separately, even though `argv` could have worked the same way. Why the difference? A design decision many decades ago, but likely one that let you quickly test `argc` to see if you have enough arguments before moving along. There's no `strlen()` equivalent for arbitrary pointer arrays.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This is a trailing NULL/terminator/sentinel value not a padding. It comes down to how Im using the array, and the compiler will put into the array only what I specify. Its precise, and I should treat it as such.

Comment: "Padding" usually means you're adding some additional values or data to make it fit a particular size, like "zero padding" for numbers to get `0020` or padding out a structure to make it a multiple of 512 bytes, etc. In this case it's a "terminator" since it indicates an end of a sequence. Padding may or may not be present, like `9999` does not need padding, but termination is generally required. In some more exotic cases you may have termination *and* padding, as you often see on some network protocols.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't always need to add an additional NULL at the end of your arrays.

This, AFAIK, is just so that the functions that use them know when they've reached the end of the arrays. Instead of having to also pass the number of elements in the array.

Comment: The code they show requires the `NULL`, used to mark the length. You don't need a `NULL` in every array of pointers to strings, but you absolutely do in what they show.

Comment: Uh. Where did I say that wasn't the case? I answered `I should always pad my char arrays with NULL from now on?` & also this particular case.

Comment: I would consider this an ambiguous question, but the person asking seems to expect the `NULL` to be added automatically. Your answer implies that the `NULL` is not needed, without explaining why it is needed in this case.

Comment: Unsure how you seem to think that I didn't explain why it's needed. `so that the functions that use them know when they've reached the end of the arrays. Instead of having to also pass the number of elements in the array.` A C programmer isn't adding NULL pointers to the end of every single array of pointers they create.

Comment: Indeed this is ambiguous question. I don't have to find the length of the array if I did not want to. Like argc I could have passed the length of the const char array to strcmp_array so I would not have to calculate its length based on a NULL termination.